# How to plot on chart only since a recent high or low?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to plot an Anchored VWAP where for example if the period is set to 20 and the highest bar in the past 20 bars is the 10th bar that the VWAP is only displayed from the 10th bar.

The recently added 'VWAP Auto Anchored' indicator by TradingView allows for plotting of a VWAP anchored to the highest bar within a period of bars and it is capable of plotting 10000 bars back. Therefore this should be possible, now. (an error message pops up when trying to view its source code)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Anchored VWAP', overlay=true)

src = input(hlc3)

period = input.int(20,title="Period")

highest = ta.highest(src, period)

//BOOL for if current bar is highest within period
ready = highest == src

//Calculates VWAP
sumSrc = src * volume
sumVol = volume
sumSrc := ready ? sumSrc : sumSrc + sumSrc[1]
sumVol := ready ? sumVol : sumVol + sumVol[1]

//Plot
temp = plot(sumSrc / sumVol)
```

The plot() function doesn't appear to allow for the deletion/modification of prior plots and the 'show_last=' only allows for an input integer.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not a perfect solution but rather a workaround (that's why I'm not writing it as an answer) but in most cases you can use lines insted of plot. In your case you might find it useful to use `if barstate.islast
    line.new(x1=bar_index-period, y1=sumSrc / sumVol, x2=bar_index, y2=sumSrc / sumVo)` instead of `temp = plot(sumSrc / sumVol)`

Comment: Thanks, that could somewhat work by drawing one line.new() from the highest bar until the 499th most recent bar and then have the rest drawn correctly with line.new(), due to the limit of 500 lines with 'max_lines_count='.... Maybe '_VWAP Auto Anchored_' indicator has different limitations compared to what we have the ability to do.